# Weird raytracing behavior for diffuse materials

Tags: c++, raytracing

I have been reading and trying out "Ray tracing in one weekend" by Peter Shirley. Everything has been going great until the diffuse material part. Basically, instead of a diffuse material, my algorithm seems to only be casting shadows from a specific angle and I have no idea from where the problem could originate from.

I have normally been following the book step by step. 
The previous sections give the correct results and the only code I have added from the last section to the diffuse material one are the functions below.

Here are the specific parts of the code for diffuse material, which basically reflect the ray into a random direction, chosen from a sphere that is tangent to the collision point (Sorry if my explanation isn't clear enough).

This is the function that take a random point from a sphere tangent to the collision point.

```cpp
vec3 random_in_unitSphere(){
    vec3 p;
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
    do{
        p = 2.0*vec3(distribution(generator),distribution(generator),distribution(generator)) - vec3(1,1,1);
    }while (p.squared_length() >= 1.0);
    return p;
}
```

This is the function that calculate the color of a pixel (By casting rays until it hits nothing)

```cpp
vec3 color(const Ray& r,Hitable *world){
    hit_record rec;
    if(world->hit(r,0.0,FLT_MAX,rec)){
        vec3 target = rec.p + rec.normal + random_in_unitSphere();
        return 0.5*color(Ray(rec.p,target-rec.p),world);
    }
    else{
        vec3 unit_direction = unit_vector(r.direction());
        float t = 0.5*(unit_direction.y() + 1.0);
        return (1.0-t)*vec3(1.0,1.0,1.0) + t*vec3(0.5,0.7,1.0);
    }
}
```

And this is the loop responsible for casting rays for every pixel of the image.

```cpp
for(int j = ny-1 ;  j >= 0 ; j--){
        for(int i = 0; i < nx ; i++){
            vec3 col(0,0,0);
            for(int s = 0; s < ns ; s++){
                float u = float(i+ distribution(generator)) / float(nx);
                float v = float(j+ distribution(generator)) / float(ny);
                Ray r = camera.getRay(u,v);
                vec3 p = r.pointAt(2.0);
                col += color(r,world);
            }
            col /= float(ns);
            int ir = int (255.99*col.r());
            int ig = int (255.99*col.g());
            int ib = int (255.99*col.b());
            outfile<< ir << " " << ig << " " << ib << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Here is the expected output : https://i.stack.imgur.com/G52MH.jpg

And here is what I get : https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYwhd.jpg

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is simply that every time you generate a random vector, you're using a *new, default-initialized* psuedorandom number generator. A random number generator contains some state, and this state needs to be preserved in order to see different results over time.

To fix this, simply make your random number generator static in one way or another:

```
vec3 random_in_unitSphere(){
    vec3 p;
    static std::default_random_engine generator{std::random_device{}()};
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(0.0, 1.0);
    do{
        p = 2.0*vec3(distribution(generator),distribution(generator),distribution(generator)) - vec3(1,1,1);
    }while (p.squared_length() >= 1.0);
    return p;
}
```

Here, I've also used `std::random_device` to (possibly) add some real-world randomness to the generator.

Comment: @Ali, do you really use output of `random_in_unitSphere()` as a direction?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux If I understood "Ray tracing in one weekend" by Peter Shirley correctly, then yes. I basically cast a ray from the hit point to this random output point. EDIT the output is actually used to compute the direction, bad use of the word "direction" sorry ^^"

Answer (score 2):

Random direction function looks wrong to me. It looks like it supposed to produce three directional cosines (wx, wy, wz) which are uniform on the sphere with radius=1, such that

wx<sup>2</sup>+wy<sup>2</sup>+wz<sup>2</sup> = 1

First problem: you construct random engine each time you are entering the function, thus all your values are the same. I just put it in Visual Studio 2017, C++14.1, x64, Win10, and two calls produced

```
-0.383666 -0.804919 0.0944412
-0.383666 -0.804919 0.0944412
```

Second problem - it is not a random dimension, length is not equal to 1.

UPDATE

Following Wolfram article http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html, here is the code which fix both problems - it does have RNG as parameter, so state would change. And second, point is now properly sampled on the unit sphere, and could be used as random direction.Just replace tuple with `vec3`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <tuple>

std::tuple<float,float,float> random_in_unitSphere(std::mt19937& rng) {
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution{};
    float x1, x2, l;
    do {
        x1 = 2.0f * distribution(rng) - 1.0f;
        x2 = 2.0f * distribution(rng) - 1.0f;
        l = x1 * x1 + x2 * x2;
    } while (l >= 1.0f);
    float s = sqrt(1.0f - l);

    return std::make_tuple(2.0f*x1*s, 2.0f*x2*s, 1.0f - 2.0f*l);
}

int main() {
    std::mt19937 rng{ 987654321ULL };


    float wx, wy, wz, squared_length;
    std::tie(wx, wy, wz) = random_in_unitSphere(rng);
    std::cout << wx << " " << wy << " " << wz << '\n';
    squared_length = wx * wx + wy * wy + wz * wz;
    std::cout << squared_length << '\n';

    std::tie(wx, wy, wz) = random_in_unitSphere(rng);
    std::cout << wx << " " << wy << " " << wz << '\n';
    squared_length = wx * wx + wy * wy + wz * wz;
    std::cout << squared_length << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE II

Second problem is that you generated points uniform INSIDE the unit sphere. So problem is not with directions - your wx, wy, wz are good wrt direction, but with length of you direction vector. Typical raytracing code is like that (in some pseudocode)

```
auto [x0,y0,z0] = start_new_ray();
auto [wx,wy,wz] = sample_direction();

float path = compute_path_in_geometry(x0,y0,z0,wx,wy,wz); // compute path from start point 0 in the wx,wy,wz direction to next object
// move ray to new surface
x1 = x0 + wx*path;
y1 = y0 + wy*path;
z1 = z0 + wz*path;

// do scattering, illumination, ... at (x1,y1,z1)
```

If (wx,wy,wz) length is not 1, then length computed as sqrt((x1-x0)<sup>2</sup> + (y1-y0)<sup>2</sup>+(z1-z0)<sup>2</sup>) WON'T BE equal to `path`. Your basic geometry rules just breaks.

Comment: To be fair, the function _is_ called `random_in_unitSphere` and not `random_unit_vector`

Comment: @alterigel It still cannot serve as random direction producer, when one does `newray = oldray + direction*length`, result would be wrong. Please check update

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! 
If I understand correctly, the direction generated by my original function is not truly "random" since the points sampled are more inclined to be chosen from specific areas right ?

Comment: @Ali your original function does not produce unit vectors, and so they're not really valid as "directions". It does produce uniformly distributed unit vectors within the _volume_ of the unit sphere. I'm a bit confused by your description too: "This is the function that take a random direction from a sphere tangent to the collision point." Where does the collision point come into play?

Comment: @alterigel my bad, the function actually choose a random point from the unit sphere. and then I cast a ray from the hit point to this random point chosen. I will edit my question right away

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux Okay I think I undertand now. Which is why you normalized the direction vector in the function you wrote. Thanks for the clarifications !

Comment: @Ali Yes, it is normalized in my function, use to if you need it